# Using a variable when accessing Eloquent collection

Tags: laravel-5

I have an array in my controller called days, which lists the days of the week and I pass it to my view.

I have columns in my DB table such as monday_start, tuesday_start, etc.

Within my view, I can access `$product->monday_start` like a good boy.

I want to check to see if there's a value in `product->XX_start` before I do something.

If I want to have a foreach loop for the days of the week and use $day to loop through my table columns, I can't figure out the syntax to append the $day variable onto my Eloquent accessor.

```
@foreach ($days as $day)
  @if ($product->$day.'_start')
    *do some stuff*
  @endif
@endforeach
```

I can't figure out how to concatenate the `$day` variable to `'_start'`

Comment: You're close, correct syntax is `->{$day.'_start'}`: https://3v4l.org/WVAXa

Comment: @TimLewis, yep, that's it. I really need to learn to ask for help earlier.